# R year quarter for in loop

Tags: r, loops, time-series, regression

I am looking to loop over my R data frame that is in year-quarter and run a rolling regression across every year quarter. I then use the coefficients from this model to fit values that are 1 quarter ahead. But would like to use quarterly date format in R?

I had similar issue with 
[Stata question] ([Stata year-quarter for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665993/stata-year-quarter-for-loop)), but revisiting it in R. Does R have the notion of year quarters that can be easily used in a loop? For e.g., one possibly round about way is

```
months.list <- c("03","06","09","12")
years.list <- c(1992:2007)

## Loop over the month and years
for(yidx in years.list)
{

  for(midx in months.list)
  {
  }
 }
```

I see zoo:: package has some functions, but not sure which one can I use that is specific to my case. Some thing along the following lines would be ideal:

```
for (yqidx in 1992Q1:2007Q4){
   z <- lm(y ~ x, data = mydata <= yqidx )
 }
```

When I do the look ahead,  I need to hand it so that the predicated value is run on the the next quarter that is yqidx + 1, and so 2000Q4 moves to 2001Q1.

Comment: See the function ?quarters to convert a date object to the calendar.  Also you maybe in interested is ?seq.Date to create a sequence of dates for your predictions.  Use the option by="quarter" to create the sequence on the 3 month basis.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need help on is how to generate quarters,

```
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
months.list <- c("03","06","09","12")
years.list <- c(1992:2007)
#The next line of code generates all the month-year combinations.
df<-expand.grid(year=years.list,month=months.list)
#Then, we paste together the year and month with a day so that we get dates like "2007-03-01".  Pass that to as.Date, and pass the result to as.yearqtr.
df$Date=as.yearqtr(as.Date(paste0(df$year,"-",df$month,"-01")))
df<-df[order(df$Date),]
```

Then you can use loops if you'd like. I'd personally consider using data.table like so:
    require(data.table)
    require(zoo)
    DT<-data.table(expand.grid(year=years.list,month=months.list))
    DT<-DT[order(year,month)]
    DT[,Date:=as.yearqtr(as.Date(paste0(year,"-",month,"-01")))]

```
#Generate fake x values.

DT[,X:=rnorm(64)]

#Generate time index.

DT[,t:=1:64]

#Fake time index.

DT[,Y:=X+rnorm(64)+t]

#Get rid of the year and month columns -unneeded.

DT[,c("year","month"):=NULL]

#Create a second data.table to hold all your models.

Models<-data.table(Date=DT$Date,Index=1:64)

#Generate your (rolling) models.  I am assuming you want to use all past observations in each model.

Models[,Model:=list(list(lm(data=DT[1:Index],Y~X+t))),by=Index]

#You can access an individual model thusly:

Models[5,Model]
```